# SQL Optimization - How would you speed up a query with a bunch of ANDs?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

```
Select * 
From <table> AS T
Where T.x = 1111 AND T.y = "fdsfsdf" AND T.z = 8888 AND ...
```

Is there a way to optimize that query at all?

Comment: You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) or the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
Select *
From t
Where T.x = 1111 AND T.y = 'fdsfsdf' AND T.z = 8888 AND . . .
```

You want an index.  For what you have provided, the best index has the three columns in any order:

```
create index idx_t_xyz on t(x, y, z);
```